# TensorFlow: Validation of model while using Monitored training session

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using dataset API to import training and validation data. I have TF 1.2. So I can use only reinitializable iterator and can't use feedable iterator since feedable iterator is available only from TF 1.4.

1) If we want to just train the network we can simply use Monitored training session. But when we want to validate while training how should we do that? Should we dump Monitored training session and use the low level Session?

```
train_dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset([FLAGS.data_dir + "train.tfrecords"])
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(_parse_records)
train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat()
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(FLAGS.batch_size)

validation_dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset([FLAGS.data_dir + "test.tfrecords"])
validation_dataset = test_dataset.map(_parse_records)
validation_dataset = test_dataset.batch(FLAGS.batch_size)

iterator = tf.contrib.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_dataset.output_types, train_dataset.output_shapes)

train_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(train_dataset)
validation_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(validation_dataset)

next_example, next_label = iterator.get_next()
loss = model_function(next_example, next_label)

training_op = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(...).minimize(loss)

with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(...) as sess:
    sess.run(train_init_op)
    while not sess.should_stop():
        sess.run(training_op)

   # HOW TO VALIDATE?
```

2) Is there any way to validate the model in the middle of an epoch using Reinitializable iterator, since it requires to initialize the iterator from the start of the dataset when we switch between iterators. Is that possible with Reinitializable iterator or we have to switch to feedable iterator to do this?

This is the example provided in the TF Dataset tutorial. Here if there are 100 iterations possible in a epoch can we validate the model at iteration 50 using Reinitializable iterator? (I think it is possible using feedable iterator)

```
# Run 20 epochs in which the training dataset is traversed, followed by the validation dataset.
for _ in range(20):
# Initialize an iterator over the training dataset.
    sess.run(training_init_op)
    for _ in range(100):
        sess.run(next_element)

# Initialize an iterator over the validation dataset.
sess.run(validation_init_op)
for _ in range(50):
    sess.run(next_element)
```

3) While using Reinitializable iterator, in the last iteration of an epoch what happens if the remaining training data samples are less than the required batch size? 
Does the few remaining samples are used with reduced batch size or they are ignored?

Comment: for your question 3, I am perplexed.  It appears that tensorflow tries to run with a smaller number of samples.  However, I later get an "Incompatible shapes" error.  This may be dependent on your model (which I may have incorrect).

Answer (score 2):

for your question 3,  TensorFlow behaves poorly, I think.  For that last batch, it may have a smaller number of samples.  This will very often (always?) cause "Incompatible shapes" errors during training.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48331954/2184122 for how to resolve this as of TensorFlow 1.4

Answer (score 2):

Please, take a look at [How to switch between training and validation dataset with tf.MonitoredTrainingSession?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095849/how-to-switch-between-training-and-validation-dataset-with-tf-monitoredtrainings?rq=1)
I think you will find the answer to both 1) and 2).
You could use a feed_dict to change the dataset to be evaluated, or just re-initialize it. From the link:

```
...
training_iterator = training_ds.make_initializable_iterator()
validation_iterator = validation_ds.make_initializable_iterator()
...
sess.run(next_element, feed_dict={handle: training_handle})
...
sess.run(next_element, feed_dict={handle: validation_iterator })
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)