# How to pad to fixed BATCH_SIZE in tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataset with 11 samples. And when I choose the `BATCH_SIZE` be 2, the following code will have errors:

```
dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames) 
dataset = dataset.map(parser)
if shuffle:
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=128)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.repeat(count=1)
```

The problem lies in `dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)`, when the `Dataset` looped into the last batch, the remaining count of samples is just 1, so is there any way to pick randomly one from the previous visited samples and generate the last batch?

Comment: Solved by padding the `filenames`.

Comment: May I ask how to pad the filenames? I tried `tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename).repeat()` and still got this problem.

Comment: Hi @Richard_wth, I just copy the filename to let the number of filenames is times of the batch size. For example, 11 filenames to 12 filenames, then the problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. But will it change the distribution of training data, since some data are copied? If so, would it be better to repeat the filename list by `k` times where `k = batch_size / GCD(num_instances, batch_size)`? GCD: greatest common divisor.

Comment: @Richard_wth, yeah, thanks for your suggestion! You are right, we may consider the method as you suggested to balance the data distribution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@mining proposes a solution by padding the filenames.

Another solution is to use [`tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/batch_and_drop_remainder). This will batch the data with a fixed batch size and drop the last smaller batch.

In your examples, with 11 inputs and a batch size of 2, this would yield 5 batches of 2 elements.

Here is the example from the documentation:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(11)
batched = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(2))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really what I want!

Comment: This might be helpful as well https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/batch_and_drop_remainder

Comment: @GPrathap: this is the same link as the one in the answer.

Comment: @Olivier Moindrot sorry, I didn't notice it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can just set `drop_remainder=True` in your call to `batch`.

```
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
```

From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch):

> drop_remainder: (Optional.) A tf.bool scalar tf.Tensor, representing
>   whether the last batch should be dropped in the case its has fewer
>   than batch_size elements; the default behavior is not to drop the
>   smaller batch.