# How to switch between training and validation dataset with tf.MonitoredTrainingSession?

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I want to use `feedable` iterator design in tensorflow Dataset API, so I can switch to validation data after some training steps. But if I switched to validation data, it will end the whole session.

The following code demonstrate what I want to do:

```py
import tensorflow as tf


graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    training_ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(32).batch(4)
    validation_ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(8).batch(4)

    handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
    iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(
        handle, training_ds.output_types, training_ds.output_shapes)
    next_element = iterator.get_next()

    training_iterator = training_ds.make_initializable_iterator()
    validation_iterator = validation_ds.make_initializable_iterator()


with graph.as_default():

    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession() as sess:
        training_handle = sess.run(training_iterator.string_handle())
        validation_handle = sess.run(validation_iterator.string_handle())
        sess.run(training_iterator.initializer)
        count_training = 0
        while not sess.should_stop():
            x = sess.run(next_element, feed_dict={handle: training_handle})
            count_training += 1
            print('{} [training] {}'.format(count_training, x.shape))
            # print(x)

            # we do periodic validation
            if count_training % 4 == 0:
                sess.run(validation_iterator.initializer)
                count_validation = 0
                while not sess.should_stop():
                    y = sess.run(next_element, feed_dict={handle: validation_handle})
                    count_validation += 1
                    print('  {} [validation] {}'.format(count_validation, y.shape))
                    # print(y)
```

The training data has 32 elements, batched with 4, so got 8 batches
we do validation every 4 steps, so I expect:

```
#  1 [training]
# 2 [training]
# 3 [training]
# 4 [training]
#      1 [validation]
#      2 [validation]
# 5 [training]
# 6 [training]
# 7 [training]
# 8 [training]
#      1 [validation]
#      2 [validation]
```

but it stops when the first validation is done:

```
# 1 [training]
# 2 [training]
# 3 [training]
# 4 [training]
#      1 [validation]
#      2 [validation]
```

So, how to use this `feedable` iterator in `tf.MonitoredTrainingSession`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to catch `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` raised at the end of the validation dataset (you can also check [the processing multiple epochs section](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#processing_multiple_epochs) in the official API for another solution using the `repeat` dataset ):

```
while not sess.should_stop():
    x = sess.run(next_element, feed_dict={handle: training_handle})
    count_training += 1
    print('{} [training] {}'.format(count_training, x.shape))

    # we do periodic validation
    if count_training % 4 == 0:
        sess.run(validation_iterator.initializer)
        count_validation = 0
        while True:
            try:
                y = sess.run(next_element, feed_dict={handle: validation_handle})
                count_validation += 1
                print('  {} [validation] {}'.format(count_validation, y.shape))
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                break
```

This piece of code prints:

```
1 [training] (4,)  
2 [training] (4,)  
3 [training] (4,)  
4 [training] (4,)  
  1 [validation] (4,)  
  2 [validation] (4,)  
5 [training] (4,)
6 [training] (4,)
7 [training] (4,)
8 [training] (4,)
  1 [validation] (4,)
  2 [validation] (4,)
```

Comment: This is really interesting, which means, internally, `sess.should_stop()` just check a state of the dataset pipeline to skip throwing that exception, and if you catch that exception yourself, then the state changed back to valid again.

Comment: What happened is that the validation `dataset` raises the `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError`, the `MonitoredTrainingSession` catches it and stops itself.